# Javascript error causing fancybox not to work on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using js no conflict on this site http://tidypools.com/tid-temp

Fancy box is not working on firefox. When I use firebug it's giving me the following error:

> Error Line: 99

Safari is also giving an error:

> TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (near '...})(jQuery); //CLOSE NO...')

When I open the script line 99 it's the very last line in my script:

```
})(jQuery); //CLOSE NO CONFLICT//
```

I've tried a js cleaner, taking off parenthesis, semicolon, moving, etc... and nothing seems to work. Any idea of what it's wrong. THANK YOU GUYS A BUNCH.

Here is the link to the js http://tidypools.com/tid-temp/js/plugins.js since it's easier to read than copying it here.

---

@Kreshnik Hasanaj

Here is the code for fancy box inside the plugin.js file:

```
        // ******************************** LIGHTBOX ********************************
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    $(".grouped_elements").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            }
        }
    })
});
// ******************************** LIGHTBOX MOBILE ********************************
$(".mobile_grouped_elements").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    margin: 5,
    nextEffect: 'none',
    prevEffect: 'none',
    autoCenter: true,
    afterLoad: function() {
        $.extend(this, {
            aspectRatio: true,
            type: 'html',
            width: '90%',
            height: '80%',
            content: '<div class="fancybox-image" style="background-image:url(' + this.href + '); background-size: cover; background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:100%;width:100%;" /></div>'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @Kreshnik Hasanaj Just paste it the code above. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not obvious from the first look on the code.

You have this:

```
//**************************************************************************
// ******************************** NO CONFLICT ********************************
jQuery.noConflict() // return `$` to it's previous "owner"
(function($) { // in here you're assured that `$ == jQuery`

// ... left out code that is not important for the problem ....

})(jQuery); //CLOSE NO CONFLICT//
```

The problem with this part is that after `jQuery.noConflict()` you miss a `;`.

For the JS interpreter it looks like:

```
jQuery.noConflict()(
    function($) {
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And because `jQuery.noConflict()`  is not returning a function you get this error.
To to avoid such problems add `;` even if it can be omitted in some situations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now, when I add the semicolon it's giving an error on line 40 which is afterLoad: function() { and still doesn't work. It wasn't giving that before. I just uploaded it.

Comment: @Daniel Well thats another problem. If you look at the error you will see that it happens in `plugins.js` and the part of the code mentioned by this error is executed before `fancybox` is loaded (check this in your HTML code). A important note: If a problem is solved and you have a new one, first search if there is a similar question already asked and if you can't find a solution yourself ask a new question. And always include which error happend (`$(...).attr(...).fancybox is not a function`).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Besides missing the semicolon as stated by t.niese, I just realized that I had an extra "})" on the 8th line of the first lightbox code which it was causing the problem.

I changed it to

```
// ******************************** LIGHTBOX ********************************
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    $(".grouped_elements").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            }
        }
    });
```

and it's working now.

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: Great that you solved your problem. A Note about `})`, i don't think that this problem was in `plugin.js` at the time i answered, because an additional `})` (if you only removed it and did not add a `}` and `)` at another place) is an `syntax error` that would have been shown before executing. And the other errors where `runtime errors`.  If the error was there at that time it was in another file loaded later. (So take care when editing code and think about tools like `jshint` or `jslint`).